# How many Number Monsters have been released in Yu-Gi-Oh thus far?

Tags: yu-gi-oh

I know a few cards of the Numbers have been released in Yu-Gi-Oh card game. How many have been released in the TCG so far?

Answer (score 4):

### 125 Number Monsters

The *Yu-Gi-Oh!* Wikia has a semantic search function that allows for creating complex queries. In this case, we want to query things that are:

- Monsters in the real-life card game (either OCG or TCG)
- Part of the "Number" archetype (including variants, like C and S)

This query can be constructed with `[[Concept:CG monsters]] [[Archseries::Number]]`. [Running the query](http://yugioh.wikia.com/wiki/Special:Ask?offset=0&limit=250&q=%5B%5BConcept%3ACG%20monsters%5D%5D%20%5B%5BArchseries%3A%3ANumber%5D%5D&p=mainlabel%3D%2Fformat%3Dul%2Flink%3Dnone%2Ftemplate%3DNavboxList&po=%3FEnglish%20name%0A) shows that there are 125 Number Monster cards at the time of this writing.

If we add `[[Category:TCG cards]]` [to the query](http://yugioh.wikia.com/index.php?title=Special%3AAsk&q=%5B%5BConcept%3ACG%20monsters%5D%5D%20%5B%5BArchseries%3A%3ANumber%5D%5D%20%5B%5BCategory%3ATCG%20cards%5D%5D&po=%3FEnglish%20name%0D%0A&eq=yes&p%5Bformat%5D=ul&sort_num=&order_num=ASC&p%5Blimit%5D=250&p%5Boffset%5D=&p%5Blink%5D=none&p%5Bsort%5D=&p%5Bheaders%5D=show&p%5Bmainlabel%5D=&p%5Bintro%5D=&p%5Boutro%5D=&p%5Bsearchlabel%5D=...%20further%20results&p%5Bdefault%5D=&p%5Bsep%5D=%2C&p%5Btemplate%5D=NavboxList&p%5Bcolumns%5D=1&p%5Buserparam%5D=&p%5Bintrotemplate%5D=&p%5Boutrotemplate%5D=&eq=yes), we find that there are 122 Number Monsters in the TCG. The 3 that exist in the OCG but not the TCG are:

- [Number 29: Mannequin Cat](http://yugioh.wikia.com/wiki/Number_29:_Mannequin_Cat)
- [Number 41: Baguska](http://yugioh.wikia.com/wiki/Number_41:_Baguska)
- [Number F0: Utopic Future - Future Slash](http://yugioh.wikia.com/wiki/Number_F0:_Utopic_Future_-_Future_Slash)

Comment: Of note is that despite this, 13 of the "base" numbers (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 26, 27, 60, 67, 75, 76, 90, and 97) have yet to be given actual cards, due to evolved forms typically sharing the same number as their base form (e.g., "Number 39: Utopia" has 7 other variants that share its number).